# Laravel - SQL Query with relational multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query that gets the officiants credentials, although that can return many rows if the user has any.

I am trying to get a query where IF one of the rows `renew` column is set to `1` then ignore it, else, return the results if its still `0`

```
$officiants = Officiant::where('status', 1)
            ->whereHas('cred',function($q) {
                $q->where('renewal', 0);
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: can you show your Officiant and cred model?

Answer (score 0):

```
$officiants = Officiant::where('status', 1)
        ->whereHas('cred',function($q) {
            $q->where('renewal', 0);
        })->with([‘cred’=> function($query) {
                $query->where('renewal', 0);
           })
        ->get();
```

If you want to get officiatns with cred then you need this query.

Comment: Officiant Cred has rows, if any of the rows return renewal 1 then ignore, else return the results

Comment: Yes, you need all creds with renewal value 0, right?

Comment: Yes, although, if any rows have '1' then DONT return

Comment: Have you run the above query?

Comment: obviously I have

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `orWhere()` it will fetch the rows with renewal=1 too

```
$officiants = Officiant::where('status', 1)
            ->whereHas('cred',function($q) {
                $q->where('renewal', 0);
                 $q->orWhere('renewal',1);    
            })

            ->with(['cred' => function($q) {
                $q->where('renewal', 1);
                $q->where('renewal', 0); 
            }])
            ->get();
```